# Как запускать тесты laravel на продакшен сервере?

Tags: php, laravel

Хочу запускать тесты по расписанию на production сервере.

Но команда `php artisan test` выдает ошибку

```
  Command "test" is not defined.  
                                  
  Did you mean one of these?      
      make:test                   
      schedule:test
```

Как заставить тесты работать в production и не является ли это плохой практикой?

Мой composer.json

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "laravel"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.0.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.12",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "laravel/ui": "^3.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.9",
        "facade/ignition": "^2.5",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.0.1",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.4.2",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^5.0",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3.3"
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/Modules"
        ],
        "files": [
            "app/Modules/Helpers/helpers.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true,
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
            "@php artisan ide-helper:generate"
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Очевидно, что это плохая практика. Тестировать приложение нужно __до__ отправки в продакшен - на тестовых стейджах. В продакшене же приложение должно делать только одно - выполнять свои непосредственные функции.

Comment: Тесты при деплое на прод должны выполняться на этапе CI/CD. Например при деплое должен тригериться пайплайн в дженкинсе или гитлабе (ну или там где у вас настроен CI), и деплой должен продолжаться только в случае успешного прохода тестов.